# how to store values in array at a specific location in c program

Tags: c, arrays

how to store values in an array at a specific location in c program?
e.g if I want to store 80000000 at first 8 positions of an array and then want to store 80000000 at the next eight values of an array to print a result 8000000080000000.
Please help.

Comment: `char array[]="8000000080000000"; printf("%s",array);`

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this:

#include<stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int arr[16];
    int i=0;
    arr[0] =8;

    for ( i=1 ; i <=7 ; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    } 

    arr [8] = 8;

    for ( i=9 ; i<= 15 ; i++ )
    {
        arr [i ] = 0;
    }

    for ( i =0 ; i <16 ; i++ )
    {
        printf ( " %d", arr[i] );
    }

    return ( 0 );

}
```

o/p 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean to say every digit of `80000000`, you want to store at different elemnts of array. you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array_length; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", array[i]);
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        ;
}
```

Input the values u want from terminal, `scanf()` will put it in array, `array_length` is maximum length of array u need to specify.

while loop removes the newline character from input stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign desired value while declaring the array variable and print as,

```
char arr[]="8000000080000000";
printf("%s",arr);
```

or if you want to store integer value then,

```
int arr[ARRAY_LENGTH]=0;
int i;

for(i=0; i<ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",arr[i]); //input the desired value
}

printf("\n" Entered value is : \n");
for(i=0; i<ARRAY_LENGTH; i++)
{
    printf("%d",arr[i]);
}
```